# Twitter API friendships/create array

Tags: php, arrays

hi i use  TwitterAPIExchange to follow users
i use this code to create friendships

```
$url_follow = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json';
$requestMethodd = 'POST';
$fields = array('user_id'=> $response);
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settingss);
$responsee = $twitter->setPostfields($fields)->buildOauth($url_follow, $requestMethodd)->performRequest();
print_r($responsee);
```

$response is array contain ids

{"errors":[{"code":108,"message":"Cannot find specified user."}]}

why??
i need use array not id

Comment: [friendships/create](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create) accept a single user id, doesn't it?

Comment: i know , can use array with it ?

Comment: if you can create only a single friendship with one request, then you can't create multiple friendship with one request.